# PHP DDD can I return null from DTO getter?

Tags: php, domain-driven-design, dto

Is that allowed or not? For example I have a method `getName()` that  returns string, but what should I return if name is not set?

Comment: I don't think your question has anything to do with DDD. Generally speaking if something is not set then a getter for it should return a `null`. Don't get hung up on such trivial details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I am aware there isn't any rule in DDD, preventing a DTO of returning Null value from a getter.

Personally I handle the Null values sourcing in DTO in a level closer to the Client/View.

So for example, if I build an MVC web app using DDD, in my interface I will have:

- My DTO - with the getter
- A DtoAssembler for my DTO which will use the getter.
- A Controller which will call the DtoAssembler. Here I will make sure that the method which calls the DtoAssembler will throw an Exception in the case of a Null value from the getter.

This way you ensure that the client will need to handle the Null value.